# Вывод значения столбца по заданному значению другого столбца

Tags: mysql

Имеется таблица `table1`. В ней есть столбцы `userID` и `col`.
Мне нужно вывести значение `col` для определенного пользователя. ID пользователя определяю с помощью переменной `$user[id]`.

Comment: Откуда берётся переменная `$user[id]`?

Comment: я не знаю. её еще нету.

Comment: Кого - _её_? Где вы вообще делаете SQL-запрос?

Answer (score 1):

Основываясь на ваших данных должно быть что-то такое:

```
$query = "select  * from table1 where userID =". $user[id];
$res = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo "Col: ".$row['col']."<br>;
}
```

Comment: Будет надеяться, что речь о PHP? :) Хотя это, бесспорно, самый вероятный вариант.

Comment: @Regent,  а даже если речь не о PHP то минимум сможем исключить этот вариант  и предложить другой :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin всё может быть... Поэтому если автор не разъяснит это в ближайшие несколько часов, то будут голосовать за закрытие вопроса.